# Signalr Retry Logic .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

We have been facing issues with reconnection in Signalr .Net Core, what are the best practices for reconnecting to signalr- hub?

Following seem to be most respected article on reconnecting. But seems outdated, isn't it?
[Best practice for reconnecting SignalR 2.0 .NET client to server hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375043/best-practice-for-reconnecting-signalr-2-0-net-client-to-server-hub)

Comment: which language client are you connecting to?

Comment: the link is outdated and a different library, but the concepts would still apply. Also, note that client and server-side libraries have on fail callbacks in the new version when creating a new connection

Answer (score 13):

The best way to do this "reconnecting" is with the `WithAutomaticReconnect` method.

So instead of writing your own reconnection logic, you can use the built in one.

First things first, you would have to remove your current reconnection logic, and add `.WithAutomaticReconnect()` to your `HubConnectionBuilder`.

Now you have two options:

### Default behavior:

The default values for this method are `TimeSpan[0, 2000, 10000, 30000, null]`, meaning that it will wait X (0, 2, 10, 30) seconds after each failed attempt to try reconnecting again. Once it reaches `null`, it will stop trying.

You can customize this array, but it will always have a null at the end, which makes it unreliable if you want it to try infinitely.
Which brings us to the next option:

### Custom IRetryPolicy

An `IRetryPolicy` indicates how many seconds the `HubConnectionBuilder` has to wait after each failed attempt to try reconnecting again.

This method runs infinitely until the connection is restored.

To implement a custom `IRetryPolicy`:

```cs
public class RetryPolicyLoop : IRetryPolicy
{
    private const int ReconnectionWaitSeconds = 5;
    
    public TimeSpan? NextRetryDelay(RetryContext retryContext)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ReconnectionWaitSeconds);
    }
}
```

So this is how it would look like in your `HubConnectionBuilder`:

```cs
.WithAutomaticReconnect(new RetryPolicyLoop())
```

Comment: Well explained thanks

Answer (score 3):

Currently you have to write your own reconnection logic. The docs have examples of how to do a naive reconnect for [Javascript client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reconnect-clients) and [.NET client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2#handle-lost-connection).

Comment: Agreed! I should have noted "automatic reconnect" versus "manual reconnect" from the client which is available.

Answer (score 0):

(Your link is referencing the .NET (4.x) client / version of SignalR, not the .NET CORE version. It's not outdated. They are distinctly different in many aspects and the are not compatible with each other. You must use a .NET CORE hub with a .NET CORE client, you cannot mix these with the older .NET (4.x) hub or client.

According to this issue back in 2017, which is still open as of this post, David Fowler said "We're looking at adding the automatic reconnect functionality back to SignalR in the next preview release."

So, depending on what version you are at and where this issue stands, you need to follow up with that project.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5282