# Signal R connection is breaking after sometime

Tags: android, kotlin, connection, signalr, signalr-hub

I've implemented an app that is based on safety purposes. This app is for the two roles i.e A and B. Both users can track the location of each other. For user A, I've implemented the Mapbox and for user B I've implemented the Google Map.

For A, Mapbox provides the default real-time navigation and for B, I've used signal R which provides the location of user A. So I can navigate marker to that particular location of the A.

It's perfect working fine when User A & B are nearby. When I'm going to test with long-distance at that time signal R connection is breaking. I've created the BaseActivity for reconnecting the signal R when it'll break & it'll reconnect. But it'll take time to reconnect.

Basically this app is for security purposes so, we can not wait for reconnecting the signal R because it takes time to reconnect.

Can you pls suggest what should I do? Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one link you should read about the reconnecting.

[Best practice for reconnecting SignalR 2.0 .NET client to server hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375043/best-practice-for-reconnecting-signalr-2-0-net-client-to-server-hub/28131378#28131378)

Also, refer below link increasing default timeout at the server-side may solve your issues.
https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/issues/61#issuecomment-111347948